# Why does VB Random.Next appear misbehave when within an If or Case statement?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, random, case

I have a snippet of code to select a string randomly from an array. It works fine, except it misbehaves when run within a select-case or If statement.

The following code gives me a random result for Petrol or Diesel, however I only ever get a return of "Electronic Injection Pump" when the randomly selected fuel is "Diesel", and I only get "Carburettor" or "Mechanical Fuel Injection" when the randomly selected fuel is "Petrol".

If I take the fuel system selection code out of the case statement it works as expected giving all the fuel system options. I have tried using an If statement but this gives the same flawed result. The .count values return their expected results of 2 and 3 respectively.

I'm really scratching my head because "Electronic Injection Pump" is second in it's array, while "carburettor" and "Mechanical Fuel Injection" are first and second in their array, so there seems no rhyme or reason to the faulty result.

```
Dim fuelLr = New Random()
        Dim fuelList() As String = {"Petrol", "Diesel"}
        Dim fuel = fuelList(fuelLr.Next(0, fuelList.Count))

        Dim fuelSystem
        Select Case fuel
            Case "Diesel"
                Dim dieselSystemLr = New Random()
                Dim dieselSystemList() As String = {"Mechanical Injection Pump", "Electronic Injection Pump"}
                fuelSystem = dieselSystemList(dieselSystemLr.Next(0, dieselSystemList.Count))

            Case "Petrol"
                Dim petrolSystemLr = New Random()
                Dim petrolSystemList() As String = {"Carburettor", "Mechanical Fuel Injection", "Electronic Fuel Injection"}
                fuelSystem = petrolSystemList(petrolSystemLr.Next(0, petrolSystemList.Count))

        End Select
```

Comment: This is a well known phenomenon - to quote the documentation - "on the .NET Framework only, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers". So just use one `Random` instance here rather than creating multiple ones.

Comment: Any question that can be answered simply by reading the documentation is a bad question on SO. You should not be asking a question here without having read the relevant documentation first. Sites like this should be a last resort; reading documentation should be one of the first things you do. You won't always find the answer but you often will and would have on this occasion. You will often also find other information that will be useful now or in the future.

Comment: thanks @jmcilhinney I have been trying to debug this for hours, but didn't find anything in reading because I was looking at If and Case statement documentation as that seemed to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Now is a good time to start learning, then, about producing [mcve]s. They're a useful debugging tool in and of themselves, and will help you to learn about *where the problem lies*, rather than thinking you automatically know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the constructor of `Random` using the system clock for its seed. If you instantiate multiple instances of `Random` in quick succession then you're likely to get the same seed and hence the same set of random values.

If you write your code like this the problem will go away:

```
Dim random = New Random()
Dim fuelList() As String = {"Petrol", "Diesel"}
Dim fuel = fuelList(random.Next(0, fuelList.Count))
Dim fuelSystem = ""
Select Case fuel
    Case "Diesel"
        Dim dieselSystemList() As String = {"Mechanical Injection Pump", "Electronic Injection Pump"}
        fuelSystem = dieselSystemList(random.Next(0, dieselSystemList.Count))

    Case "Petrol"
        Dim petrolSystemList() As String = {"Carburettor", "Mechanical Fuel Injection", "Electronic Fuel Injection"}
        fuelSystem = petrolSystemList(random.Next(0, petrolSystemList.Count))
End Select
```

The problem has been resolved in .NET 6 and above. You also then get a special shared instance of random in `Random.Shared` that is also thread-safe.

---

If you want to try to clean up your code a bit and avoid all of the nasty `Random` calls, here's an extension method that might help:

```
Module Extensions

    Private __random As New Random() 
    
    <Extension>
    Public Function Sample(OF T)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of T)) As T
        Dim collection = TryCast(source, ICollection(Of T))
        Return If( _
            collection Is Nothing, _
            source _
                .Select(Function (x, n) New With { .Value = x, .Index= n }) _
                .Aggregate( _
                    CType(Nothing, T), _
                    Function (a, x) If(__random.Next(x.Index + 1) = x.Index, x.Value, a)), _
            collection(__random.Next(collection.Count)))
    End Function

End Module
```

Now your code can be written with the new `Sample` operator:

```
Dim fuelList() As String = {"Petrol", "Diesel"}
Dim fuel = fuelList.Sample()
Dim fuelSystem = ""
Select Case fuel
    Case "Diesel"
        Dim dieselSystemList() As String = { "Mechanical Injection Pump", "Electronic Injection Pump" }
        fuelSystem = dieselSystemList.Sample()

    Case "Petrol"
        Dim petrolSystemList() As String = {"Carburettor", "Mechanical Fuel Injection", "Electronic Fuel Injection"}
        fuelSystem = petrolSystemList.Sample()
End Select
```